# How many edges are in a clique of n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I believe the answer is $\frac12(n-1)^2$, but I couldn't confirm by googling, and I'm not confident in my ability to derive the formula myself.

Comment: So you think a clique of $2$ vertices has exactly $\frac12$ edges?

Comment: Oh yeah, how silly. Good thing I checked.

Comment: $\frac12 (n^2 - n)$?

Comment: I think I would upvote this question if it included your (as Chris points out, incorrect) derivation.

Comment: @Ben Honestly I just half-remembered the formula, didn't make much effort to derive it myself.

Comment: @MikeL: I think I would upvote this question if you made much effort, then :P

Comment: Provided you know the answer to be $\tbinom{n}{2}$, you can prove it by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clique has an edge for each pair of vertices, so there is one edge for each choice of two vertices from the $n$. So the number of edges is:

$$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!\times(n-2)!}=\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$$

**Edit:** Inspired by Belgi, I'll give a third way of counting this! Each vertex is connected to $n-1$ other vertices, which gives $n(n-1)$ times that an edge is joined to a vertex. As each edge is joined to exactly two vertices, there must be $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ edges.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: nice, I wish I could upvote again :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to calculate what Matt said it to this: number the vertices from $1$ to $n$, and consider the graph with $n$ vertices but with no edges.

Take the first vertice: it has vertics to the other $n-1$ vertices, connect those $n-1$ vertices

Take the second vertice: it has vertics to the other $n-1$ vertices - but one of them is already connected - connect the other $n-2$

do this untill the last vertice. you get that you connected $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1$ vertices which is an arithmetic proggrestion whose sum is $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n$

Comment: Yes, I think this is how I once learned it. Thank you.